# google cloud shell is temporarily unavailable try after few minutes

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

while activating my cloud shell it is showing google cloud shell is temporarily  unavailable try after few minutes.Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Append `&cloudshell=true` in the end of the URL and refresh.
If still does not work, clear cookies or try in Incognito mode.

If still does not work, perhaps it's just temporary problem. Wait a couple of minutes hence the problem might be server-side.